# Download a file using a blob URL in safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

Using Chrome or Firefox I can easily do something like this in my HTML:

```
<a href="http://urlofmyblob.com/blobid"/a>
```

This immediately starts a download when the anchor linked is clicked in most browsers.  However, in safari this only opens a new tab with the contents of my blob in text form.  Does safari support downloading blobs from a remote URL? Also, is there a way I can do this using the href property in an anchor link?

Comment: It seems you may have to modify the headers in the response, if you've access to the server:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124955/download-attribute-on-a-tag-doesnt-work-on-ie-safari-or-opera

Comment: Which version of safari ? See http://caniuse.com/#feat=blobbuilder

Comment: The fact that I can only make this work via a response from a server is frustrating. I have created a file blob and want to download it from a link on a page. Works fine in Chrome and Firefox. But not safari. Since I have no server involved here, I don't have the option of modifying that response header. Oh well. Safari will just get bad support for this.